# Altering featureinfo_text_html.xsl in ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 to display images?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-10.3, getfeatureinfo, template

In my WMS layer I have a URL pointing to an image. Does anyone have an example of how to manipulate the HTML template to display the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would look something like:

```
[standard template]
...
<xsl:variable name="quote">"</xsl:variable>
...
[standard template]
...

<xsl:for-each select="esri_wms:FeatureInfo">
<tr>
    <xsl:if test="(position() + 1) mod 2">
        <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#eeeeee</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="esri_wms:Field">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="some test for your attribute with the url...">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat(&lt;,'img src=',$quote,esri_wms:FieldValue,$quote,'/',&gt;)" />
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="esri_wms:FieldValue"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

Comment: If the url is the value of a field called "Fotografie" and the value always begins with https...is there an elegant way to define the test- ie <xsl:when test="some test for your attribute with the url...">

Comment: Try `text()[starts-with(.,'https')]` as the test